# Controlling # of Network Calls in Angular via RxJS Not Working as Expected

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular app I am receiving some filter selections in a middle sibling component and then passing them along to the final receiving component, like so:

```
@Output() sendFilterValues = new EventEmitter();

onFilterValuesReceived({ 'zip' : zipArray, 'firstName' : firstName,
'lastName' : lastName, 'language' : language, 'location' : location, 'branch' : branch })
{
    this.sendFilterValues.emit({ 'zip' : zipArray, 'firstName' : firstName,
    'lastName' : lastName, 'language' : language, 'location' : location, 'branch' : branch });
}
```

I then gather these filter values in the receiving component, like so:.

```
<grid [records]="records"
    (sendChange)="pageChange($event)"
    (sendFilterValues)="onFilterReceived($event)">
</grid>
```

And then I make the network call, like so:

```
public onFilterReceived(values)
{
    let filters = {};

    if (values) {
        filters = values;
    }

    this.route.params.subscribe(
        (params: any) => {
            this.page = params['page'];
        }
    );

    let fn = resRecordsData => {
        this.records = resRecordsData;
    };

    console.log('onFilterReceived() firing...'); // I see this 10 times in the console

    this.streamFiltersService.getByFilters(
        this.page - 1, this.pagesize, this.currentStage, this.language = filters['language'], this.location = filters['location'],
        this.zipcode = filters['zip'], this.firstName = filters['firstName'], this.lastName = filters['lastName'],
        this.branch = filters['branch'], fn);
}
```

This is (sort of) working.

However... because the filter values come in one after another I end up making ten network requests. And, sometimes, when re-loading the component after the user has navigated away and then returned, these network calls (which are asynchronous) return out of order (as can happen of course), and I end up with non-filtered data displayed on the screen.

So, what I'm trying to do, since this returns an `observable`, is use some kind of RxJS operator to effectively only make one network call. What I've tried so far, however, doesn't seem to be having any effect.

The network request, look like this in the service:

```
public getByFilters(page, pagesize, stage?, language?, location?, zipcode?, firstName?, lastName?, branch?, fn?: any)
{
    return this.apiService.get({
      req: this.strReq, reqArgs: { page, pagesize, stage, language, location, zipcode, firstName, lastName, branch }, callback: fn });
}
```

Now, since I want to make just one call, I tried adding a couple of different RxJS operators, like `takeLast`, `mergeAll`, `combineAll` like so:

```
public getByFilters(page, pagesize, stage?, language?, location?, zipcode?, firstName?, lastName?, branch?, fn?: any)
{
    return this.apiService.get({
      req: this.strReq, reqArgs: { page, pagesize, stage, language, location, zipcode, firstName, lastName, branch }, callback: fn }).takeLast;
}
```

This seems to have no effect, because the `console.log` I have in my `onFilterReceived()` function still shows this function firing 10 times.

Am I missing something here? How can I ensure the network call only happens once here? I'm open to suggestions based on the above code to resolve this situation - via RxJs or another solution.

Comment: If the `onFilterReceived` method is called 10 times, then no wonder that your api service the same number of times, dont you think?

Comment: But isn't the whole point of the RxJs operator to limit that to one call? Please explain what I'm missing. Do I need to throttle this before it gets to the network request, or can I do it there? I'm unclear on this.

Comment: of what rxjs operator?

Comment: I mentioned three of them above. `takeLast` for example.

Comment: 3 things: 1 - you should subscribe to router params in your constructor not in your event handler.  2 - your event handler should just emit the filter to an Rx Subject, 3 - you can then use rx magic to join the router params to the filter subject, debounce the resulting stream, then use switchMap() to make api calls and keep things in order.

Comment: Sounds promising, would love to see a scaffold of what this looks like based on my existing code. Because I'm under a time-crunch, the simple solution the better based on my existing code.

Comment: Also, @Brandon, so is using `flatMap`, or '`takeLast`, or `combineAll` like I am in my code above effectively doing nothing? Is there not an operator I can add to my network request (see above example) to control the number of calls made?

Comment: Will post something tonight when I have time

Comment: Cool. Would really appreciate that.

Comment: @Brandon, also, I'm wondering if I can simply convert the observable to something like a BehaviorSubject, and then use an operator like takeLast on it -- right here in the final receiving component?

Comment: What does `getByFilters` return?

Comment: @Picci, as far as I can tell, it returns an observable.